# why does 'on mouse...' function strangely

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a program that allows a user to explore a 3D function via two 2D slices (in two windows).  The function is encoded in two tables, one for each dimension.  To select the slice shown in one window, the user enables 'editDim' checkbox, then click-drags in the other window.  When 'editDim' is unchecked, the user can pan and zoom each window.  The problem is that when in 'editDim' mode, if I click and drag the mouse cursor moves out of the pink-shaded drawing region, the pan-zoom kicks in.  I've put a simplified version into jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/eric_l/PB6aK/.
I've added log messages that show mouse events, and when not click-dragging (normal mouse movements), I see no events for the regions surrounding the drawing regions.

```
this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(self.xscale).y(self.yscale).on("zoom", function() {self.redraw() } );

this.div = d3.select(this.anchor).append("div");
this.svg = this.div.append("svg")
    .datum(this.data[this.select].values)
    .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
    .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
    .call(this.zoom)
    .on("mouseover", function () {
        console.log("on mouseover");
        self.div.style("background", "lightyellow");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        console.log("on mouseout");
        self.div.style("background", null);
    })
    .on("mousemove", function () {
        console.log("on mousemove");
        if (editDim)
        {
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
            self.update();
        }
    })
    .on("mousedown", function () {
        console.log("on mousedown");
        self.mousedown = true;
        if (editDim)
        {
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
            self.update();
        }
    })
    .on("mouseup", function () {
        console.log("on mouseup");
        self.mousedown = false;
    });
```

I'm using the D3.behavior.zoom method - maybe it is associated with a DOM element that is larger than the DOM element that my 'on mouse...' events are associated with?  If so, how do I get both sets of events to cover the same extent of the screen and execute mutual-exclusively (again, selected by the 'editDim' checkbox).
When I change the DOM element that the 'on mouse...' events are associated with to the 'div' element just above the 'svg', I no longer get mousedown events.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You attached events to `g` element, not `svg`,

I changed the code to the following, to attach to svg:

```
this.div = d3.select(this.anchor).append("div");
    var SVG = this.div.append("svg")
        .datum(this.data[this.select].values)
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom);
    this.svg=SVG
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
        .call(this.zoom);
     SVG.on("mouseover", function () {//........
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PB6aK/2/)

Comment: That didn't quite solve the problem, though it did change it a little.  The pan and zoom still kicks in, although at a further point - now as the cursor leaves the window (table cell).

Comment: not very understand, I answered why your events do not fired, I not sure what is your goal.

Comment: also i not see functinal changes in one or another case